# Update DOM elements when state is updated using setTimeout() React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, settimeout

I have the following code in React. This code uses a time expensive function that performs some coputations over a large number of data. in the begining the state is filled with an array that says no computations. When the button is pressed, I want that array of the state to be filled with waiting, and after each iteration over i is complete, the element on potition i to be 'Done'. The problem is that by using set timeout, the DOM elements are not updating untill the whole function is over. Ignore the computations in the for, they are meaningless in this example. To have an ideea the function performs polynomial fit over the given data. My problem is how can I update the Dom elements while the function is running, So i can knwow which data is done and which is computing in real time

```
const Component = ( {data1, data2} ) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState(Array(data1.length).fill('No Computations'))
  const timeExpensiveFunction = () => {
     // data1.length = 10
     let variable0
     let variable1
     let variable2
     let variable3

     for(let i = 0; i< data1.length; i++){
       //data1[i].length = 40 000
        for(let j = 0; j< data1[i].length; j++){
           variable1 += data1[i][j]
           variable2 += variable1*data2[i][j]**3
           variable3 += data2[i][j]**2
           variable1 += data1[i][j]*data2[i][j]
        }
     
   setTimeout(() => {
                setState(state => {
                    return[
                        ...state.slice(0,i),
                        'Done',
                        ...state.slice(i+1),
                    ]
                })
            },1000)
   }
   return([variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4])
  }

  const randomFunc = (e) => {
     setTimeout((e) => setState(Array(data1.length).fill('Waiting ...')),1000) 
     timeExpensiveFunction() //Duration depends on the number of data, it is usually higher that 10-15 seconds
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {state.map((element) => (
             {element} //This does not update with the function setTimeout. It sets after the expensive computation is over

          ))}
       </div>
       <div>
           <button onClick = {(e) => randomFunc(e)}>press</button>
       </div>
     </div>
       

)
}
```

Comment: What does `timeExpensiveFunction` do? Does it tie up the main thread for a full minute??

Comment: *"`setTimeout(console.log(state),2000)` //This returns what it should be"* I find that comment ahrd to believe. That will log the **old** value of `state`, not the updated one.

Comment: *"`const [state, setState] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`"* Surely this has a `useState` somewhere? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: so are you asking how to make "Waiting..." being rendered _before_ heavy function starts and everything freezes?

Comment: Yes, I want map function to render having the state waiting before heavy function. Also during the heavy function, to set state with 'Done' and render at each itteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You must use `useState` and `useEffect` to set a state and re-render the DOM.
You can use like below:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Component = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
  const [isPress, setPress] = useState(false); // use it to not call a method on first render 
  const timeExpensiveFunction = () => {
     // lot of work here
  }

  const randomFunc = (e) => {
     setState([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
     setPress(true)
  }

  useEffect({
    if (isPress) setTimeout(() => timeExpensiveFunction(),1000)
  }, [state])

  return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {state.map((element) => (
             {element}

          ))}
       </div>
       <div>
           <button onClick = {(e) => randomFunc(e)}>press</button>
       </div>
     </div>
       

)
}
```